# What are the halachic considerations regarding davening after staying up all night on Shavuot?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, sleep, shavuos

There is a wide-spread minhag to stay up all night on the evening of Shavuot and learn until *shacharit* in the morning. I know that when people do that, there are some necessary changes to the morning davening. What are some of the halachic issues that come up with morning davening after staying up all night and how are those issues properly addressed?

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8110/1713

Comment: One of the biggest concerns, in general, is that people fall asleep during davening. That defeats the purpose of davening and, for that matter staying up all night if you daven improperly. Years ago, my rav insisted that learning ended about an hour before netx so that people could sleep a bit, and davening commenced about 1/2 hour before sof z'man kri'at shema.

Answer (score 3):

## Eating before davening

The first issue that can come up is the [prohibition to eat before davening shacharit](http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5760/pekudei.html). In many places where groups of people gather to have an all-night learning seder, food is provided. Once the time of *alot ha-shachar* arrives, one should stop eating or else he has violated the prohibition of eating before davening.

Next, there are a few morning *brachos* that you cannot say if you have not slept. They are as follows with proper actions listed in order of preference:

## *Elokai Neshama*

1. Have someone who has slept lying down for 30+ minutes recite the blessing and have you in mind to fulfill your obligation.
2. If there is no one around who slept 30+ minutes, have in mind to be *yotzei* with the bracha of *Mechayeh Meitim* in *Shmoneh Esrei*.
3. Simply go without this bracha.

## *Birchot ha-Torah*

1. Have someone who has slept lying down for 30+ minutes recite the blessings and have you in mind to fulfill your obligation. (Then say *yevarechecha* and *eilu devarim* to yourself.)
2. Have in mind for the bracha of *Ahava Rabba* to count for *birchot haTorah*. Then make sure to learn something at some point after *shemoneh esrei*.
3. If you did not do the first two options, have someone getting up when you get home (perhaps your wife) say it for you or ask a person getting an aliya to have you in mind with the first *bracha* and then read quietly along for a few pesukim.
4. Simply go without

([See here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8114/1713))

## *Hama'avir Sheina Me-eynai*

1. Have someone who has slept lying down for 30+ minutes recite the blessing and have you in mind to fulfill your obligation (note the *yehi ratzon* paragraph that follows the first line is part of the bracha. Do not reply *amein* until after *gomel chasadim tovim le-amo Yisrael*).
2. Have someone getting up at home (perhaps your wife) say it for you when you get home.
3. Simply go without

## The bracha on *al mitzvat tzitzit* on a *tallit katan*.

1. If you wear a *tallit gadol*, after *Mi-she-yakir* make a bracha on your *tallit gadol* having in mind the *tzitzit* that you are wearing.
2. If you don't wear a *tallit gadol* have someone who does be motzi you with his bracha.
3. Make a bracha on a different pair of *tzitzit* and put them on (you can do this when you get home assuming you don't have a separate *tallit katan* at shul)
4. Just keep wearing your *tzitzit* but don't make a bracha.

Notes:

- It is generally the case in most shuls that one person who slept the previous night will be appointed to be *motzi* everybody else with the brachot that they cannot say.
- When you are being *yotzei* by someone else's bracha, you should respond *amein* to the bracha, but **not** *barukh hu u-varukh shemo* ([see here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/11000/1713)).
- This answer is largely based on a document entitled "Shavuos Morning: A Guide to the Weary and Perplexed" compiled by R' Kalman Zinnes handed out at shacharit davening this past Shavuot at a shul in Chicago.

Comment: Note that there are plenty of opinions that some of these brachot can be said even without having slept (eg. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8121/759). Being machmir for the Mishna Berura's position has become quite popular recently, but it is not the only one.

Comment: Is your wife obligated in Birkot haTorah Mideorayta that she can be motziah you? Also, why did you not include the perhaps optimal option of saying it after you nap that day??

Comment: @DoubleAA Good point about saying it after the nap. I'll contact him to find out where in the priority list that would fall. As for your question about the wife, I'd say the answer is apparently yes she is able to be motziah a man (at least according to the poskim that R' Zinnes consulted for this sheet)

Comment: Frankly, nearly every single Rishon would say you have to say it again after the nap even if you did say it in the morning. Better perhaps to daven without having said it (which may not be a problem anyway as it is prayer not study) and say it after the nap before your learning in the afternoon, than to say it before the prayer but have the whole afternoon be b'issur accd to nearly every rishon.

Comment: We get a sefardi to recite them..

Comment: While this question technically spoke about issues with the morning davening, I think the issue of missing the blessing of HaMapil the night before is sufficiently related to be worth including in this answer.