# How does one handle ברכות התורה when learning through sunrise?

Tags: halacha, zemanim, birchos-hatorah

With sunrise being pretty late in some parts of the globe, how does someone handle the question in the title? If one is learning before and up to sunrise, do they stop and make a blessing when sunrise arrives?

Comment: מחלוקת בין רבינו תם ושאר התוספות כמו בסוכה

Comment: Did you intend to ask in the case where one slept during the night?  The question is harder in the case where one didn't sleep.

Comment: @ze'ev - this was inspired by my just starting the daf yomi :) I'm getting up moderately early to do the daf, sometimes before עלות.

Comment: I though you were going to say inspired by the Daf yomi because it came up in the Daf

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 47:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.47.13?lang=bi) rules that one who wakes up early to learn should make *birchot hatorah* before he starts learning, even if that is before the start of daylight. One does not repeat the blessings after it becomes light.

Comment: What if somebody learns all night up until there's a new light of day?

Comment: @oakad https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8110/birchas-hatorah-everyone-was-awake-all-night